# How to ignore a child's width in a flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please check out the following code:

```html
<div style="display: flex; background: black; max-width: 600px;">
  <div style="background: yellow">AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA</div>
  <div style="min-width: 0;">
    <div style="background: cyan">BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB</div>
    <div style="background: magenta; overflow-x:auto; width:100%; min-width: 0;">
      <div style="width:3000px"> 
        CCC CCC
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background: green">DDD DD DDDDDD D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a parent flex divided in 2 columns.

In the right column, one of the elements (the magenta one) is very large, but that's OK with me, I'd like to keep the scroll behavior.

However, because the magenta element is very wide, the yellow element shrinks, which bothers me.

I would like the proportions between the left and the right columns to be **exactly** the same as in this snippet:

```html
<div style="display: flex; background: black; max-width: 600px;">
  <div style="background: yellow">AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA</div>
  <div style="min-width: 0;">
    <div style="background: cyan">BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB</div>
    <div style="background: green">DDD DD DDDDDD D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I proceed to "ignore" the magenta element's width, so the size of the yellow column doesn't change?

NB: **I don't want to use fixed widths**! I want my columns to share the available space depending on what they contain (only the magenta element should be ignored)

Thanks

Comment: You can use `min-width` on your columns to achieve that.

Comment: try assigning `flex-basis: 0` for the child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

**Use `flex-basis`.** The `flex-basis` should be set on the longer element - if I want to explain it very simply, it's similar to `max-width` but specific to `flex`.

**The `flex-basis` property determines the initial size of a flex item before the remaining space is distributed by the system during layout.**

For example, **if we set the `flex-basis` property of a flex item to `200px`, it means that the item's initial size will be 200 pixels** (regardless of its content or the size of other elements). Then, along with the other flexible items and the available space, the Flexbox model automatically distributes the appropriate space among the content items in the proper proportions.

```html
<!-- Solution -->

<h3>With Too Large Element - Use "flex-basis"</h3>
<div style="display: flex; background: black; max-width: 600px;">
  <!-- First Column -->
  <div style="background: yellow;">
    AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA
  </div>
  <!-- Second Column -->
  <div style="min-width: 0; flex-basis: 100%;"> <!-- Use "flex-basis: 100%" on too width element -->
    <!-- Cyan -->
    <div style="background: cyan;">
      BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB
    </div>
    <!-- Magenta (too large) -->
    <div style="background: magenta; overflow-x:auto; width: 100%; min-width: 0;">
      <div style="width: 3000px;"> 
        CCC CCC
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Green -->
    <div style="background: green">
      DDD DD DDDDDD D
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- To Compare -->

<h3>Original (Without Too Large Element)</h3>
<div style="display: flex; background: black; max-width: 600px;">
  <!-- First Column -->
  <div style="background: yellow;">
    AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA
  </div>
  <!-- Second Column -->
  <div style="min-width: 0; flex-basis: 100%;">
    <!-- Cyan -->
    <div style="background: cyan;">
      BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB
    </div>
    <!-- Green -->
    <div style="background: green">
      DDD DD DDDDDD D
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- To Compare -->

<h3>Original (With Too Large Element)</h3>
<div style="display: flex; background: black; max-width: 600px;">
  <!-- First Column -->
  <div style="background: yellow;">
    AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA
  </div>
  <!-- Second Column -->
  <div style="min-width: 0;">
    <!-- Cyan -->
    <div style="background: cyan;">
      BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB
    </div>
    <!-- Magenta (too large) -->
    <div style="background: magenta; overflow-x:auto; width: 100%; min-width: 0;">
      <div style="width: 3000px;"> 
        CCC CCC
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Green -->
    <div style="background: green">
      DDD DD DDDDDD D
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution, is that you can use `min-width` on your columns to achieve what you want with the downside that you need to specify a fix `min-width`.

```html
<div style="display: flex; background: black; max-width: 600px;">
  <div style="background: yellow; min-width: 300px;">AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA</div>
  <div style="min-width: 300px;">
    <div style="background: cyan">BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB</div>
    <div style="background: magenta; overflow-x:auto; width:100%; min-width: 0;">
      <div style="width:3000px"> 
   CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background: green">DDD DD DDDDDD D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Since you don't want to use fixed widths** on the elements, this approach is suited for you. You can use the `flex` property on your yellow background element as someone mentioned in the comments, but deleted it.

```html
<div style="display: flex; background: black; max-width: 600px;">
  <div style="background: yellow; flex: 0 0 auto;">AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA</div>
  <div>
    <div style="background: cyan">BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB</div>
    <div style="background: magenta; overflow-x:auto; width:100%; min-width: 0;">
      <div style="width:3000px"> 
   CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background: green">DDD DD DDDDDD D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Third solution:** You can use `flex-basis: 100%` on your yellow element which sets the initial main size of a flex item and it will do the trick. Have a look [here](https://codepen.io/coolis6/pen/PoxGZpM).

Comment: I cannot use solution #1 because I cannot use fixed widths, and in solution #2 the yellow column is way larger than in the expected result (my second snippet) :(

Comment: PS: I changed the yellow content to AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA to make it more obvious

Comment: Try `flex-basis: 100%`. I think works the way you want. In the snippet it looks smaller, so try it out in your code.

Comment: Please highlight the use of `flex-basis` as it is the perfect solution to the problem.

Comment: Where should I use flex-basis exactly?

Comment: @BorisK on your yellow element.

Comment: @coolis Nope, if I add `flex-basis: 100%` in the style of the yellow element, the width of the yellow element is way smaller than the one in the expected result (my second snippet).

Comment: @coolis, Keep the original div with a width of 600px. It looks similar now because you changed the original width to 1000px.