# white-space: nowrap with flex: 1; child width too small to fit text

Tags: css, flexbox

I can't find any solution to have 2 same size divs that will fit text inside it in one line. Looks like white-space: nowrap width is not taken into consideration after I set on parent width: fit-content.

They should be as small as possible, always same size, no wrapping text to second line.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 130px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.button1 {
  background: red;
}

.button2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="button button1">Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button2">A Long Text Button That Has Greater Width </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to increase the parent width. Add `width: 100%` on the parent div and set min-width on the children divs to 50% and you are done :) Or use `display: grid`

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you want to add `width: fit-content;` on the parent?

Comment: Just to confirm, you want the two `div`s to be the same width, but as small as possible such that neither will need to wrap their text?

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms yes exactly, they should be as small as possible

Answer (score 2):

can be done with CSS grid:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 130px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.button1 {
  background: red;
}

.button2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button button1">Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button2">A Long Text Button That Has Greater Width </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution # 1 (with flex)

- the width of the elements is equal to the width of the **shortest element**

Use `flex-basis`.

> The `flex-basis` property determines the initial size of a flex item before the remaining space is distributed by the system during layout.

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76521790/15167500) - Stack Overflow Answer

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
}

.button {
  flex-basis: 100%; /* HERE (in child element) */
  padding: 10px 20px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.button1 {
  background: red;
}

.button2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<h2>Solution (with 2 elements)</h2>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="button button1">Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button2">A Long Text Button That Has Greater Width </div>
</div>

<h2>Solution (with more elements)</h2>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="button button1"># 1 Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button2"># 2 A Long Text Button That Has Greater Width </div>
  <div class="button button1"># 3 Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button2"># 4 A Long Text Button That Has Greater Width </div>
  <div class="button button1"># 5 Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button1"># 6 Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button1"># 7 Short Text</div>
</div>
```

#### Solution # 2 (with flex and javascript)

- the width of the elements is equal to the width of the **longest element**

Use JavaScript to set children's width to width of longest element.

```js
// Get all container
const flexContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.flex')

// Run function to all container
flexContainers.forEach((flexContainer) => {
  // Get all children from current container
  const children = flexContainer.querySelectorAll('.button')
  // Find longest child
  let longestChild = children[0]
  children.forEach((child) => {
    if (child.scrollWidth > longestChild.scrollWidth) {
      longestChild = child
    }
  })
  // Set width of children
  children.forEach((child) => {
    child.style.width = `${longestChild.scrollWidth}px`
  })
})
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
}

.button {
  flex-basis: 100%; /* HERE (in child element) */
  padding: 10px 20px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 130px;
  width: 100%;
}

.button1 {
  background: red;
}

.button2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<h2>Solution (with 2 elements)</h2>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="button button1">Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button2">A Long Text Button That Has Greater Width </div>
</div>

<h2>Solution (with more elements)</h2>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="button button1"># 1 Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button2"># 2 A Long Text Button That Has Greater Width </div>
  <div class="button button1"># 3 Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button2"># 4 A Long Text Button That Has Greater Width </div>
  <div class="button button1"># 5 Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button1"># 6 Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button1"># 7 Short Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: any solution without scroll?

Comment: I just added `overflow`. Remove it, and add row-break to child element: `white-space: wrap;` (My answer updated.)

Comment: this doesn't comply with the request: `no wrapping text to second line`

Comment: Well, you can provide a fixed width to the flex-basis, but unfortunately, this setting will either apply a fixed value to all elements or resize them based on the width of the smallest element (here a Short text by `min-width: 130px;`).

Comment: You can implement a JavaScript code that finds the longest element within the flex container and sets its length as the `flex-basis` value. I'll update it with an example based on answer.

Comment: Answer updated a second solution with javascript manipulation.

Comment: #1 is with overflow which I dont want, and also without JS if possible

Comment: If you want to set the width according to the length of the longest text, it is inevitable. The mentioned GRID solution in @Temani_Afif's comment also only creates two identical fields and does not produce the same result you requested. With CSS, you can only adjust to the smallest size, as seen in my "Solution #1" in the answer. In order to fully achieve what you requested, it is necessary to use JavaScript to determine which field is the longest and adjust the width of each field accordingly: see "Solution #2".

Answer (score -3):

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 130px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.button1 {
  background: red;
}

.button2 {
  background: green;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="button button1">Short Text</div>
  <div class="button button2">A Long Text Button That Has Greater Width </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain how the code given is different from the original code, and how it fixes the issue.